# Why can't I put my car into drive unless I put it into d3 first? Same with reversing, I need to shift gears into neutral first. Please help me

Tags: automatic-transmission, daewoo

A month ago when I tried to start my car and drive after having parked it out my office it would rev but not shift into any gears so I took it to a mechanic and he told me that he had fixed the problem.
True to his word i didn't experience the same problem again but this morning the same problem had recurred so I played around with the selector and found out that I can drive if I put it into D3 first before shifting into D, similarly in order to reverse I have to put it into N before shifting to R.
I was wondering if anyone had any idea why that might be as I am to my wit's end with this car. Any help would be very much appreciated.

For anyone who is wondering I own a Daewoo Nubria (2001 model).

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say clutch, do you mean the selector stick?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4):

The most likely I can think of is that the cable that connects the selector to the transmission needs adjusting.  When you are selecting drive, the transmission is seeing it still in neutral, so you have to push it further into d3 to get the transmission to see that you are selecting drive.

Does the dashboard show which gear is selected?  Does the dashboard agree with the selector or what the transmission is doing?

Comment: Yeah I meant the selector stick, sorry for that, and thank you for your reply it really helped. Turns out you were right and now my car is working properly again.